# Adding class on load with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a class on page load using javascript. I'm currently learning javascript so bear with me. I am just trying to change the background color of an element as a test shown below. I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null"

I know I am more than likely missing a very simple step here so would appreciate any advice.

Thanks all

```js
window.onload = onPageLoad();

function onPageLoad() {
    document.querySelector('.home').classList.add = ('active');
}
```

```css
.bg-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
}

div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-yellow"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remove `()` from `window.onload = onPageLoad();` when assign, or else it will invoke it immediately.

Second, it should be `.classList.add('active');`, not `.classList.add = ('active');`.

Third, your element's class selector is `.bg-yellow`, not `.home`.

Stack snippet

```js
window.onload = onPageLoad;

function onPageLoad() {
    document.querySelector('.bg-yellow').classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.bg-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
}

div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-yellow"></div>
```

Comment: thanks so much! I knew it would be something simple. Thanks so much again

Answer (score 1):

Remove the = sign. As I recall, .add () is a function. Also search .bg-yellow, not .home in the querySelector function, assuming that is what you want to add the class to given your code samples. Or add 'home' to the classes of the .bg-yellow div e.g.

`<div class='bg-yellow home'><div>`.

The error you are receiving is because .home does not exist in your page according to the sample you gave. Therefore the .querySelector will return null (see [the standard](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-queryselector)) when searching for that selector, and there is no classList defined for `null` objects.